# Best way to rearrange positioning of images/divs with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I took a peek at the source of http://wonderwall.msn.com and noticed how all the span tags that the blocks of the wall have don't seem to be associated with any ID. It makes me very curious how they are able to accomplish the animated repositioning of elements when you click on one of the blocks/images without associated ID.

I am curious how you can click on say an image and get other images around it to move to the side. Is it some sort of formula or algoirthm?

I would like to accomplish getting say, 5 spans/blocks, clicking on one, and getting others to animate/move to the sides.

Answer (score 3):

IDs are not necessary and often harmful.  You don't need them, generated or otherwise.

When you put an element on a page with an ID, you're making the claim that there should be only one of whatever it is.  Seldom is this true.  More often, what you want to do is associate some behavior with some of the elements on the page, of which there may be many, one or zero.

In this case, there are lots of little image dealies, which when clicked, rearrange themselves.  I don't have an algorithm for you for calculating how they should move, but here's a framework for how you could achieve the same with jQuery.

```
// create jQuery plugin for highlighting and shuffling brick dealies
(function($){

  function expandify() {
    var href = this.attr('href');
    // create a popup containing the href
    return this;
  }

  function shuffle() {
    this.each(function(index, elem){
      // calculate new position and move the element there.
    });
    return this;
  }

  $.fn.expandify = expandify;
  $.fn.shuffle = shuffle;

})(jQuery);

// attaches behaviors to elements on the page after they've loaded
// either $.ready, or window onload, or after some ajaxing takes place
$('.wallBrick')
  .click(function(e){

    $(e.target)
      .expandify();

    $('.wallBrick')
      .not(e.target)
      .shuffle();

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The IDs are generated via JavaScript on-the-fly. You won't see it in the source, but you'll see it if you inspect it with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).